# Known side effects when using lock statement in ConcurrentDictionary.GetOrAdd?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, concurrentdictionary

I had some issues when adding to an Entity Framework `DbSet` from multiple threads from inside a `ConcurrentDictionary` `ValueFactory` method. I tried to eliminate that issue by introducing a `lock` statement. This seems to have some strange side effects though. In some rare and random cases, my code throws a `KeyNotFoundException`, even though the programming should prevent that from happening. I guess that I oversee something.

```cs
using (ESBClient client = new ESBClient()) { // WCF SERVICE

    client.Open();

    // Limit the maximum number of parallel requests
    var esbLimiter = new SemaphoreSlim(4);

    ConcurrentDictionary<string, DataEntry> dataEntryDict  = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, DataEntry>(
        await db.DataEntries
            .Where(de => allObjIDs.Contains(de.PAObjID))
            .IncludeOptimized(de => de.WorkSchedules)
            .ToDictionaryAsync(a => a.PAObjID, a => a)
    );


    // Get WorkOrderDataSet02 for each data entry number
    await Task.WhenAll(allDataEntryNumbers.Batch(20).Select(async workOrderBatch => {
        await esbLimiter.WaitAsync();

        Debug.WriteLine($"Starting for new batch after {s.ElapsedMilliseconds} with parallel {esbLimiter.CurrentCount}");

        try {
            int retryCounter = 0;
            getWorkOrderDataSet02Response gwoResp;

            retryCurrentWorkOrderDataSetResp:
            try {
                gwoResp = await client.getWorkOrderDataSet02Async(
                    new getWorkOrderDataSet02Request(
                        "?",
                        companyGroup.Key,
                        string.Join(",", workOrderBatch.Select(wob => wob.DataEntryNumber)),
                        "WNTREIB",
                        "?",
                        "act,sales",
                        "D"
                    )
                );

            } catch (System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException ex) {
                // Retry up to 3 times before finally crashing
                if (retryCounter++ < 3) {
                    await HandleServiceRetryError("getWorkOrderDataSet02Async", retryCounter, s.ElapsedMilliseconds, ex);
                    goto retryCurrentWorkOrderDataSetResp;
                } else
                    throw;
            }

            // Iterate over all work orders returned by the ESB
            foreach (dsyWorkOrder01TtyWorkOrder currDetail in gwoResp.dsyWorkOrder01) { // dsyWorkOrder01 IS AN ARRAY OF OBJECTS. IT COMES FROM A WCF CALL. PAObjID IS UNIQUE.
                // Get or create element
                DataEntry currentEntry = dataEntryDict.GetOrAdd(
                    currDetail.Obj,
                    key => {
                        DataEntry newDe = new DataEntry();
                        lock (db.DataEntries) { // I INTRODUCED THOSE LOCK STATEMENTS
                            db.DataEntries.Add(newDe); // THIS IS THE LINE THAT WAS PROBLEMATIC IN THE FIRST PLACE
                        }
                        return newDe;
                    }
                );

                // Set regular fields
                currentEntry.ApplyTtyWorkOrder(currDetail, resourceDict); // THIS METHOD APPLIES THE PAObjID PROPERTY
            }

            // Delete all elements, that were not provided by the service anymore
            lock(db.DataEntries) { 
                workOrderBatch
                    .Where(wob => !gwoResp.dsyWorkOrder01
                        .Where(wo => wo.DataEntryNumber.HasValue)
                        .Select(wo => wo.DataEntryNumber.Value)
                        .Contains(wob.DataEntryNumber)
                    )
                    .ToArray()
                    .ForEach(dataEntry => {
                        try {
                            db.DataEntries.Remove(dataEntryDict[dataEntry.ObjID]); // THIS LINE THROWS THE KeyNotFoundException
                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                            throw new Exception($"Key {dataEntry.ObjID} not in list.", ex);
                        }

                    });
            }

            // Update progress
            progress.Report(.1f + totalSteps * Interlocked.Increment(ref currentStep) * .8f);

        } finally {
            Debug.WriteLine($"Finished for batch after {s.ElapsedMilliseconds} with parallel {esbLimiter.CurrentCount}");
            esbLimiter.Release();
        }

    }));
}

// HERE'S THE APPLY METHOD
public void ApplyTtyWorkOrder(dsyWorkOrder01TtyWorkOrder src, Dictionary<(string Name, byte ResourceType), int> resourceDict) {
    Deleted = false;

    DataEntryNumber = src.DataEntryNumber.Value;
    PAObjID = src.Obj; // PAObjID IS APPLIED HERE
    IsHeader = src.IsHeader;
    Pieces = Convert.ToInt16(src.ProductionQty);
    PartNo = src.Article;
    JobNo = src.WorkOrder;
    StartDate = src.StartDate;
    FinishDate = src.EndDate;
    FinishedPA = src.WorkOrderStatus == "R";

    // Update methods
    UpdateFromTtyCustomer(src.ttyCustomer?.FirstOrDefault());
    UpdateFromPart(src.ttyPart?.FirstOrDefault());
    UpdateFromSalesDocHeader(src.ttySalesDocHeader?.FirstOrDefault());
    UpdateWorkSchedules(src.ttyWorkOrderActivity, resourceDict);
}
```

I added an UPPERCASE comment to every line I would consider relevant.

I have no idea why this error happens. From my understanding, I only try to get an entry from the `dataEntryDict` dictionary `dataEntry.ObjID` keys that I've added before in the same iteration of the loop.

Before I introduced the two lock statements, the line marked with "THIS IS THE LINE THAT WAS PROBLEMATIC IN THE FIRST PLACE" throw an exception sporadically: "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute." After digging into the code of EF, I realized that this should have something to do with the way how the `DbSet.Add` method is implemented.

Are there any known side effects when using a `lock` statement inside the `ValueFactory`?

Answer (score 1):

```
lock (db.DataEntries) { // I INTRODUCED THOSE LOCK STATEMENTS
    db.DataEntries.Add(newDe); // THIS IS THE LINE THAT WAS PROBLEMATIC IN THE FIRST PLACE
}
```

The issue is that `db.DataEntries` is not a thread-safe collection but it is being accessed concurrently by multiple threads. All EF objects are not thread-safe.

Using locking seems like a good solution here. Make sure that you catch all the places.

It is often better to split the concurrent part off from the sequential part. Make *only* the `client.getWorkOrderDataSet02Async` call concurrent and collect the results in a collection. Then, process the results sequentially.

Comment: Ok, looks like I'm on the right track. But can you tell me, why adding the lock introduced the KeyNotFound problem? Doesn't the lock block the thread? For me, this whole thing has the disgusting smell of a race condition. I feel like the command `dataEntryDict[dataEntry.ObjID]` is executed before the element was actually added to the dictionary under some very rare cisrumstances, Would that be possible?

It's also strange, that I can't reproduce that issue on my local machine, nor in the testing environment. It only happens on the production server.

Comment: I admit I didn't fully read the code (because it is a lot). I really recommend that you minimize the concurrent portion. Likely, the bug simply goes away and the code becomes much better. I now tried to find a bug and did not succeed. But I also do not understand how this code is supposed to be safe. What ensures that `dataEntryDict` always contains an object for any ID being looked up? I don't see any such assurance.

Comment: The code is for synchronizing two systems (where the other system is the leading one). There are basically two ways to add an entry to that list. First, I gather all data, that is in my local database (not postes). That's also added to that dict. Then I get a list of all data entry numbers in the source system. `allDataEntryNumbers` is a list of all distinct DENs. Therefore, `dataEntryDict` should contain a respective entry either from the database or the WCF service at the point, where the exception is thrown. In my whole code, I never make up any object ID.

Comment: PS:There is a 1 to 1 relationship between the object ID and the data entry number.

Comment: Can there be duplicates? Maybe the same entry is removed twice. In general, I'd solve a data synchronization problem by building the source and destinations as lists, then using set operations on them such as Except or Intersect. I have written myself a full join helper method as well. This problem comes up all the time.

Comment: I actually thought about a similar solution. But for now, the program seem to run stable. Me did a few bulk imports today and for now, we didn't receive a single error. I wonder what will happen over night.